# Is it possible to have non-generic method return generic type?

Tags: c#, java, generics

In Java I can easily write:

```
public interface MyInterface<T extends Object>
```

and then have a method which determine the T at runtime like:

```
public MyInterface<?> DetermineObjectAtRuntime()
```

But in C# where `<?>` is not available and I need to call the method with type; which means I need to know the type before hand.

1. Is it possible to return generics type from non-generic method?
2. If not, how can I work out the type to call such generic method if I have an object instance with that type?

For people who are not sure what this is for - I have a set of data structures which are using different enums as field indexers. All the messages extends from a common generic interface with that enum as type variable. Now I need to work out a method which deserialize all different types of messages from a byte[] array.

Comment: I have no idea where you are going with this. Can you give us an example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Generic method return values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712567/c-sharp-generic-method-return-values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, you can have generic methods:

```
class Foo<X>
{
  public T DoSomethingFunky<T>( ... )
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

But there's no way to have a wildcard type — a big fail in C#. It would be very useful in a lot of situations where you that it is a `Widget<T>` but you don't care about the particulars of `T`.

For instance, WCF throws `FaultException<T>`, where the various flavors of `T` are service specific. There's no way to catch something like `FaultException<*>` without simply catching the base `Exception` class and using reflection to inspect the caught exception to see if it's an interesting `T`. This prevents handling service faults in a generic way.

I believe the reason is that a concrete generic class (`Widget<int>`) are not really subtypes of the generic class (`Widget<T>`) it "inherits" from. The generic class is simply used as a template to compile a new specific class.

The one thing you could do, is have your generic template (`Widget<T>`) inherit from a non-generic base class (`Widget`) and have your method return that:

```
class AbstractWidget { ... }
class Widget<T> : AbstractWidget { ... }
.
.
.
public Widget GetGeneric Widget()
{
   /* flavor determinated at runtime */
}
```

It's incumbent upon the caller to decide what to do with its Widget.

Comment: Thanks. I really dislike the idea that Widget<int> isn't inherited from Widget<T> - but anyway it's the language's choices :(

Answer (score 5):

In C#, which does not have type erasure, there are several ways to work around not knowing a type argument at compile-time:

- **Non-generic subset**: If it happens to be the case that the methods of `MyInterface<T>` that you need don't involve `T`, then you can extract that portion of the interface into a base interface and return the base interface instead.

  Pro: No runtime type shenanigans.

  Con: Modifies the type (moving methods to a new base interface), breaking binary compatibility.
- **Type checking wrapper**: Make a `RuntimeTypeCheckedMyInterface<T>` class that implements `MyInterface<object>` by delegating to a `MyInterface<T>` after type checking. Have the method return a `MyInterface<object>`, created by wrapping the `MyInterface<whatever>` inside a `RuntimeTypeCheckedMyInterface`.

  Pro: Works with any existing interface type, without modifying it.

  Con: Introduces "does T=object really mean object, or does it mean unknown type"? ambiguity.
- **Manual type erasure**: Make a variant of `MyInterface<T>` that doesn't have a T like `MyInterfaceOfUnknownType`. Make `MyInterface<T>` inherit from `MyInterfaceOfUnknownType`. Have your method return `MyInterfaceOfUnknownType`.

  Pro: Acts basically identical to Java, with `MyInterfaceOfUnknownType` = `MyInterface<?>`.

  Con: Pollutes `MyInterface<T>` with non-generic methods. When the methods differ only by return type you have to disambiguate with a name change. Modifies the type (breaking source and binary compatibility).
- **Screw the types**: Have the method return `object` or `dynamic`. Cast conditionally and appropriately.

  Pro: Initially easy to do.

  Con: Harder to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

"But in C# where '< ? >' is not available and I need to call the method with type; which means I need to know the type before hand."

You can use `dynamic` instead of `<T>` for example:

```
dynamic Foo (dynamic Input) {return Input;}
```

The compiler determines the type at runtime.

Comment: Almost - just in my case I have T : IConvertible and system complains dynamic doesn't extend from IConvertible.

Comment: when you use dynamic you don't need to define any type or interface. You can leave everything for the runtime. The compiler also doesn't show any error during the compile time, but if something goes wrong an exception can be thrown.

Comment: Thanks - but I wanna stronger type checking than just dynamic :(

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to add an extension

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static T As<T>(this object obj)
    {
        return (T)obj;
    }
}
```

the above will provide you a .As() method